# Python/Kivy : Move one TextBox to another TextBox from enter in dynamic add row

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am using Python-2.7 and kivy.Now i am doing dynamic add `row` click on +Add More button.
Can someone tell me how to add row dynamic by enter key When `enter` into last `TextBox` of every `row` instead of +Add More button  and cursor `focus` on first column of new row?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 400)

class User(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'


<TextInput@TextInput>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    padding_y: 3


<Row>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 40

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200

    TextInput:
        id:test1
        text: ' '
        width: 300
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: test2.focus = True

    TextInput:
        id:test2
        text: ' '
        width: 300
        multiline: False

<Rows>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"

User:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 5

        ScrollView:
            Rows:
                id: rows


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .2
            size_hint_y: .2

            Button:
                text: "+Add More"
                on_press: root.add_more()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

1. Remove the *+Add More* Button
2. Add *focus: True* to the first *TextInput, test1*
3. Add callback, *on_text_validate: app.root.add_more()* to the second *TextInput, test2*

### test.kv

```
TextInput:
    id: test1
    focus: True
    text: ' '
    width: 300
    multiline: False
    on_text_validate: test2.focus = True

TextInput:
    id:test2
    text: ' '
    width: 300
    multiline: False
    on_text_validate: app.root.add_more()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - AppStartup]
[image: Img02 - Input]
[image: Img03 - New Row Added after user pressed ENTER]